# Why single html <p> tag is being spilt into two <p> tags with a <br> tag between them?

Tags: python, html, css, django, deployment

Below is my template html tag ( django):

```
<p class="card-text cfs-9 cfc-grey">{{i.post|safe|truncatechars:100}}</p>
```

```
This tag render totally fine on local server, but on production server, this single <p> tag is being split into two <p> tags and an extra <br> tag appear out on nowhere between them. I think the issue is with 'truncatechars' but i could not figure out. Below is view source code from both local and production server.
```

Local Server view page source:

```
<p class="card-text cfs-9 cfc-grey">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the…</p>
```

Production server view page source:

```
<p class="card-text cfs-9 cfc-grey"><br><p>In this post I'll be demonstrating how we can deploy Django website on…</p>
```

I tried {{i.post|truncatechars:10|safe}} instead of {{i.post|safe|truncatechars:100}} but the problem remains.Tried using 'truncatewords' but still same problem.

Comment: Please create https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the `i.post` contains HTML that opens tags, but does not close these properly. You can work with [**`|truncatechars_html:…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html) to automatically close tags that have been opened, but not closed (yet):

```
<p class="card-text cfs-9 cfc-grey">{{ i.post|safe|truncatechars_html:100 }}</p>
```

Comment: I did try that, rendering is still the same.